# Simplify this trig equation

Tags: trigonometry

Simplify:

$$
\cos({\frac{5\pi}{4}} - x)
$$

I figure I need to make use of one of these identities:

$$
\sin{x} = \cos({\frac{\pi}{2}} - x)
$$

Or:

$$
\cos{x} = \sin({\frac{\pi}{2}} - x)
$$

Am I on the right track?

Comment: No. Use the angle difference formula for cosine.

Comment: As @BenjaminWang's comment suggests, the formulas that you referred to are all based on the underlying idea that $$\cos(a-b) = \cos(a)\cos(b) + \sin(a)\sin(b).$$  Here, $~5\pi/4~$ is a special angle whose sine and cosine are known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question makes use of three identities:
$$\sin(a+b)=\sin a\cos b+\cos a\sin b \\
\cos(a+b)=\cos a\cos b-\sin a\sin b \\
\cos (a-b)=\cos a\cos b+\sin a\sin b$$
You can check out [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities) link for the proof and other related identities.

By the third identity, $$\cos(\frac{5\pi}{4}-x)=\cos\frac{5\pi}{4}\cos x+\sin\frac{5\pi}{4}\sin x$$

By the first and second identity, $$\cos\frac{5\pi}{4}=\cos(\pi+\frac{\pi}{4})=\cos\pi\cos\frac{\pi}{4}-\sin\pi\sin\frac{\pi}{4}=-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \\
\sin\frac{5\pi}{4}=\sin(\pi+\frac{\pi}{4})=\sin\pi\cos\frac{\pi}{4}+\cos\pi\sin\frac{\pi}{5}=-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$

Subtittuting it back, we get $$\cos(\frac{5\pi}{4}-x)=-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(\sin x+\cos x)$$

Comment: That doesn't seem much simpler but thank you.

Comment: Actually, I believe the second step where you use the first and second identity are unnecessary since we know what $\cos{\frac{5\pi}{4}}$ and $\sin{\frac{5\pi}{4}}$ are.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what question you're asking.Perhaps you can consider $\frac{5\pi}{4}$ as $\pi + \frac{\pi}{4}$,and use the following triangular identities

$$
\begin{aligned}\sin(\pi+\alpha)&=-\sin\alpha\\\\\cos(\pi+\alpha)&=-\cos\alpha\end{aligned}
$$

or

$$
\begin{aligned}&\sin(\pi-\alpha)=\sin\alpha\\\\&\cos(\pi-\alpha)=-\cos\alpha\end{aligned}
$$

I hope I can help you!